# Push notification to android with php codeigniter

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, rest, push-notification

I'm new in android and in php. I now start learning php with codeigniter framework. How I can send push notification to android with this framework?

Thanks for help for new Programmer!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to paste below function in your controller and need to change GCM key.

```
public function androidPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

        $registrationIds = array($registration_ids);
        $msg = array('message' => $message, 'title' => 'test notification', 'vibrate' => 1, 'sound' => 1);
        $fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIds, 'data' => $msg);
        $headers = array('Authorization: key=', 'Content-Type: application/json');

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = json_decode($result);
        if ($data->success == 1) {
            $return = 'SUCCESS';
        } else if ($data->failure == 1) {
            $return = 'FAILURE';
        }
        return $return;
    }
```